# Changing StyleSheet on Webpage Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this script almost to 100% of where I want it, but I just cannot get it stop flickering when the window re-sizes over 865px.

I basically built it change the style of my website from mobile to desktop when the window gets past a certain size. For the most part I built it using the awesome other questions asked on this site, but I just cannot get the end of it.

JavaScript:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {        
    if ($(this).width() > 865) { 
        if (x != 'Desktop') { 
            var x = 'Desktop';
            $('head link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IIS/_Stylesheets/HTMLPageReset.css" type="text/css" />');
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IIS/GRCAWebsite/_Stylesheets/GRCANew2015.css" type="text/css" />');
        }
    }
    if ($(this).width() < 865) { 
        if (x != 'Mobile') { 
            var x = 'Mobile';
            $('head link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IIS/_Stylesheets/HTMLPageReset.css" type="text/css" />');
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IIS/GRCAWebsite/_Stylesheets/GRCANew2015_Mobile.css" type="text/css" />');
        }
    }
});
```

It works great in the mobile view, but in the desktop view the page constantly reloads the script whenever the window is re-sized. I think it has something to do with my **x** variable, but

I call JQuery as well.

Comment: You realize there is something called media queries right?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do here is much better suited to [media queries in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: CSS can handle this with a media query and then you don't need JS. If you still want to do it with JS You can prevent the constant refiring of the script during resize by storing the size and comparing it to the previous one. If your previous size is on one side of 865 and the current on the other side fire the relevant function. one direction needs to include 865. Right now if the window is exactly 865 it won't resize.

Comment: I had not heard of this media query. To google!

Comment: @CodyBrown What you are doing is the harder way to go for sure, However it is a great technique to learn. There are tons of things you can do with your code that css media queries will never do. I would suggest learning media queries first but keep this technique in mind because it will certainly be useful in the future.

Comment: Media Queries are way easier. Figured it out in 5 minutes as oppose to 4 hours. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Well since you are telling the browser to do something at below 865px and something else above 865px, your issue is most likely that you forgot about the lonely 865px itself. Try adjusting one or the other like this

`if ($(this).width() > 864)` or `if ($(this).width() < 866)`

That way 865px will now be captured.